# What does a blinking CPU light mean?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, computer-building

I built a headless server with a Ryzen 5 2600 and a B450 Tomahawk Max (and some other components). It worked normally until recently. Now, when I try to turn it on, the "CPU" EZ Debug light is blinking. It blinks on for about 3 seconds than off for about 3 seconds. If I disconnect the CPU power wire, the light is solid. What error does that signify? I replaced the CPU, but it continues happening. Is it a problem with the motherboard?

Comment: What does the manual say?

Comment: It goes without saying that disconnecting the CPU power isn't going to prove anything, your system won't post without it, verify all other compodents are fully functional.  Makes sure firmware is flashed to a supported version that supports your CPU.

Comment: @Ramhound The manual says nothing about when the LED is flashing.

Comment: @ramhound I happen to have that manual here (just upgraded my cousins rig that uses the same motherboard). That LED isn't supposed to blink. It is either OFF (all good) or ON (bad CPU, CPU not seated properly in the socket or unsupported CPU). Manual doesn't cover this.

Comment: Also, the CPU looks physically fine and all the other components wouldn't have any effect on the CPU light. Maybe one of the motherboard circuit traces is broken?

Comment: @DaedalusMind Are you sure the CPU-heatsink/fan is installed correctly? A heatsink that puts uneven pressure on the CPU may cause an intermittent CPU good/CPU bad situation. I had the same thing happening on my own Ryzen 5 system last year.

Comment: I turned all the screws on the included cooler until they wouldn't turn. Would it be a good idea to try turning on the computer after unscrewing the cooler, but leaving it on the CPU?

Comment: @DaedalusMind - I am an Intel guy, but every video I have seen, indicates you are supposed to only tighten it a certain amount.  "Until it wouldn't budge" is to tight.  How about the firmware, have you confirmed, you are running a supported firmware with the CPU?  **You should avoid turning the computer on if the screws are not tightened, that is the way the CPU is installed in the socket if it doesn't have enough pressure or too much you run into this problem.**

Comment: I think I'm running supported firmware, because it worked normally for some time before breaking. The screws turned with a small amount of resistance until they suddenly stopped turning, which I think they were designed to do.